# Ubuntu 23.10 with Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)

Tags: wireless, intel, 23.10

Just installed Ubuntu 23.10 and I'm on a fibre line in which I am only getting about 50 Mbps down using my Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a) built into my new workstation. I have looked around and tried all of the methods using the search to fix my issue. I know it's not the card itself or my router as the card worked perfectly on Win 11 prior to me wiping my SSD clean for ubuntu. I have also tried to connect via wifi hotspotting my phone and get the same speed cap of 50 Mbps.

Has anyone been able to fix this issue on 23.10? Seems like it's not a driver issue either considering the intel drivers are upstream in the kernal and this device is quite old now.